# How to determine the main class in a java application?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

When I load a sample application in netbeans (anagrams that comes with it) and I hit run, the program just runs .. how can it determines the entry point for the program (class which has main method) ...

Comment: Is the project a Netbeans project, or just a generic directory of java files? If it's a Netbeans project, it could be that whoever create it already created the run configuration. If it's not, then it could be that it has a [manifest file that defines `Main-Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html), and Netbeans is picking that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes that can be run have a small green triangle on their icon in the "projects" view.
If a default class is set to run with the project, you can see it by right-clicking the project and selecting "properties". Then in the project properties, go to "Run" and you should be able to see the main class.

Comment: Ah in properties under run tab you can select the main class... great thanks